# Can i download the Contoso Sample Files for SharePoint

Tags: excel, word

I would like to download the Contoso sample files used in SharePoint 2013 training, is there any place that I can get them.

Answer (score 1):

You can download them here: [code.msdn.microsoft.com](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepoint/)